# How can i modify my html form on click to enable a button that changes the form input

Tags: javascript, html

What i requeire is very very simple, but im quite stuck, im trying to modify an old html form and spice up with some javascript or react.  All i want to do here is Say for example the original form (`<form>`) is

Username:
Password:

And i would like to add a button, and on click it changes the form to

Login Key:

Hiding both Username and Password fields. bascially replace them with the Login Key Form.    Any answers are very well aprecciated.   Thanks.

Comment: So, you want a javascript solution and you're stuck currently.  What specifically are you stuck on?  Do you have any javascript already written?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a lot about javascript, but maybe you can use PHP to do this writing something like

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['buttonNewForm']))
    {
        echo "......your new form.......";
        echo "<form action=page.php method=post>
           <button name='buttonOldForm'>Button</button>
        </form>"
    }
    else
    {
        echo "......your old form.......";
        echo "<form action=page.php method=post>
           <button name='buttonNewForm'>Button</button>
        </form>"
    }
?>
```

The file must be **page.php**

I didn't check the code, but it should work as you want showing at the first time your old form.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery hide and show to accomplish what you're wanting.

```
$("#thisIsYourBtnID").click(function() {
   $("#div").hide(); //this is your div that has username and password inputs in it
   $("#div2").show(); //this is your new div showing login key form
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I made a quite simple **javascript function**, is it what you were trying to do ?

```html
<html>

<body>

    <form>
        <div id="divNo1">
            <label>Username : </label>
            <input type="text" />
            <br />
            <label>Password : </label>
            <input type="text" />
        </div>

        <div id="divNo2" style="display:none">
            <label>Login Key : </label>
            <input type="text" />
        </div>
    </form>
    <button onclick="changeDisplay()">Button</button>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeDisplay() {
        var div1 = document.getElementById("divNo1");
        var div2 = document.getElementById("divNo2");
        if (div1.style.display == 'none') {
            div1.style.display = '';
            div2.style.display = 'none';
        } else {
            div1.style.display = 'none';
            div2.style.display = '';
        }
    }

</script>

</html>
```